# Is this sentence acceptable: I am running faster than you do

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if the following sentence: "I am running faster than you do" is a correct sentence.

I know most of the time it should be "I am running faster than you are" or "I run faster than you do", but I just want to know if in a specific context this sentence can be used.

For example, I am a track and field athlete, and I am training with someone else. I know how fast he can run and he's now watching me practicing. This guy always beats me when we practice together. But this time is different.

I see the timer as I am going to go through the finish line this time and I know that I am faster than he usually is. So I yell, "Look! I am running faster than you do!"

Is this sentence acceptable in the context above?

Comment: I would add “usually”:  “I am running faster than you usually do.”

Answer (score 1):

It's an excellent question, and I think you have the right idea.

I think I would word it this way:

> I am running faster than you run!

instead of saying:

> I am running faster than you do!

(I think your version is grammatical for the situation you describe; however, it's such an odd sentence that I think *run* sounds better than the more vague *do*.)

Moreover, I agree with the comment saying how the sentence could be made even more clear by adding an adverb like *usually, typically*, or *normally*.

> I am running faster than you normally run!

Fact is, though, it would be a very rare sentence indeed, as most runners would wait until after their run was finished, and say:

> I ran faster than you typically run!

Answer (score 0):

**Running:**

> The action or movement of a runner

**Do:**

We use ***do*** to talk about actions in general, when we do not specify exactly what the action is and According to Cambridge Dictionary do can also be used to avoid repeating a verb or verb phrase:

> She runs much faster than he does.

**so saying:**

> I am running faster than you do

is acceptable usage.